# Divide IplImages?

Tags: opencv

How to divide 2 IplImages in OpenCV?. .
    dirn->imageData = (float*)(drv32fy/drv32fx); gives

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘IplImage*’ and ‘IplImage*’ to binary ‘operator/’
```

Also, i tried using `cvDivide()` but it gives
error: ‘cvDivide’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Can you may explain what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either [cvDiv() or cv::divide()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#divide).